# Change the Checkbox field update for multiple request

Tags: trigger

I am getting multiple request from other system, i am updating in the field Update__c with 
value when value is true at that time check-box is checking, suppose if i get multiple request 
only for 1st request the check box is checking remain all cases not

How can i change this for bulk update ****quotes[0].Sys_checkchild__c =true; // How can chage for this bulk updates. it checking for only 1 record.****

```
  trigger targerquaote on Quote_Item__c (after insert,after update) {
 public boolean checkallchildrecs;
 set<id>idset=new set<id>();
 set<id>quoteidset=new set<id>();
 for(Quote_Item__c  qq:trigger.new){
 idset.add(qq.id);
 quoteidset.add(qq.Quote__c); 
 }

  list<Quote_Item__c>qit1=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset];
  list<Quote_Item__c>qit2=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset AND (Updated__c = 'true' OR Updated__c = 'sss')];
  list<Quote_Item__c>qit3=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset AND Updated__c = 'false' ];
 List<Quote__c>  quotes=[select id, name,Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c   where Id IN:quoteidset];
 if (quotes.size() > 0) {
 integer wholerecords=qit1.size();
integer specificrecords=qit2.size();
for (Quote__c quote : quotes) {
 if(wholerecords==specificrecords){
**quotes[0].Sys_checkchild__c =true; // How can chage for this bulk updates. it checking for only 1 record.**
 update quotes;

}else if(qit3.size()>0){

quotes[0].Sys_checkchild__c =false;
quotes[0].Updated__c = 'false';
update quotes;
}
}

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a version of your trigger with the special case of index 0 removed which I think is what you are asking for:

```
trigger targerquaote on Quote_Item__c (after insert,after update) {

     set<id>quoteidset=new set<id>();
     for(Quote_Item__c qq:trigger.new){
         quoteidset.add(qq.Quote__c); 
     }
     list<Quote_Item__c>qit1=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset];
     list<Quote_Item__c>qit2=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset AND (Updated__c = 'true' OR Updated__c = 'sss')];
     list<Quote_Item__c>qit3=[select id,name,Quote__c  from Quote_Item__c where Quote__c IN:quoteidset AND Updated__c = 'false' ];

     List<Quote__c> quotes=[select id, name,Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c where Id IN:quoteidset];
     if (quotes.size() > 0) {
         integer wholerecords=qit1.size();
         integer specificrecords=qit2.size();
         for (Quote__c quote : quotes) {
             if(wholerecords==specificrecords){
                 quote.Sys_checkchild__c = true;
             }else if(qit3.size()>0){
                 quote.Sys_checkchild__c =false;
                 quote.Updated__c = 'false';
             }
         }
         update quotes;
    }
}
```

Note that instead of performing (time and governor limit) expensive queries to get the counts (such as `wholerecords`) you could just loop over the Trigger.new collection and add up the totals like this:

```
trigger targerquaote on Quote_Item__c (after insert, after update) {

     Set<Id> quoteidset = new Set<Id>();
     Integer wholerecords = Trigger.new.size();
     Integer specificrecords = 0;
     Integer falserecords = 0;
     for (Quote_Item__c qi : Trigger.new) {
         quoteidset.add(qi.Quote__c);
         if (qi.Updated__c == 'true' || qi.Updated__c == 'sss') {
             specificrecords++;
         }
         if (qi.Updated__c == 'false') {
             falserecords++;
         }
     }

     List<Quote__c> quotes = [select Id from Quote__c where Id IN :quoteidset];
     for (Quote__c quote : quotes) {
         if (wholerecords == specificrecords) {
             quote.Sys_checkchild__c = true;
         } else if (falserecords > 0) {
             quote.Sys_checkchild__c = false;
             quote.Updated__c = 'false';
         }
     }
     update quotes;
}
```